# Silverlight Evaluated Permission in Browser

Tags: silverlight

I am programming a silvelight application that is a Ftp manager like file zila.
this is my application image.

[image: My Aplication Image]

My left application part use Directory.Exist('x') Method that when my application start because it does not have evaluated permission, my left part application does not work.

I search the web and I found that I must sign my application and change a registery key but my users do ot understand it and can not do it.

Comment: Can you please explain more about your issue. Does the right part works?

Comment: With elevated trust you can only access special folders like Documents, Music, Pictures, and Videos however  trusted applications cannot access non-user folders except through the OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog classes.